# Alternative proof of the cardinality of the set of all mappings

Tags: set-theory

Can anyone please tell me if there is any other proof for the cardinality of all mappings, that is not by induction, i.e., not this one (http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_Set_of_All_Mappings) ?

Thanks

Comment: You could just *define* $\vert T\vert^{\vert S\vert}$ to be $\left\vert T^S\right\vert$ and you're done! Actually for the non-finite case, that's probably the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A=\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements, a mapping $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is defined uniquely by choosing $f(a_1)$ ($m$ options), then $f(a_2)$ ($m$ options again), and so on until you choose $f(a_n)$ (as always, $m$ options). By the product rule, there are $m \times m \times \cdots \times m$ ($n$ factors) overall, namely, $m^n$.